# How to stop hyperledger explorer backend

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I'm working on running hyperledger explorer on my hyperledger fabric blockchain network, I followed the step explained [HERE](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer)

I ran the start.sh which is running "node main.js"
I found some issues in channel name\port, I need to stop the script.
I can see on the command shell that the blockchain is still receiving requests!
How can I stop running the script, it seems that client.js is periodically running every 1 second.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve the issue by killing "node main.js" process as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
process_num=$(ps -elf | grep -v grep | grep main.js |  awk '{print $4}')
if [ "X ${process_num}" != "X "];then
    kill ${process_num}
fi
```

if you have better option, please drop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pidof node` it will return the PID of node. You can then use `kill` with the PID you want.

You can also use `sudo kill $(pidof node)` and kill all Node JS process (may be undesirable if you have other Node server running).

Or if you remember the port it was running you can use `lsof -t -i:<YOUR_PORT>` and get the PID of the stuff running on that port. Again you can chain it `sudo kill $(lsof -t -i:<YOUR_PORT>)`